# react native share geolocation with other device

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation

Is it possible to share user's location to other user (of the same app)? I want to build a geolocation sharing app that pings/notifies user A once user B has crossed a certain radius. Doable with firebase or a similar third party? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand, what you want to do is:

1 - If user A passes near user B (on the street), notify both users that they are nearby?

2 - Do you want to share the user's location through an application and send it to another user, either through a social network or email?

If it is option 1, you will have to obtain the latitude, longitude and accuracy of the users and keep sending and obtaining it from Firebase every so often (or through a socket connection like socket.io) and make a match and calculate the radius or distance between both points.

Comment: thanks for responding! Closer to option 2. I'd like to notify user A (through a push notification) when user B enters a location. Will that require a socket connection or would it be a simple post from firebase once location data is sent?

Comment: You can use both options, if you do not have many users using the application I recommend using sockets, otherwise a basic insert with firebase should work for you.

Comment: awesome, thank you! would I be able to give permission to user A to access user B's location? similar to what find my friends does